# Match exactly with strstr

Tags: php, strstr

How can I use `strstr` to match the content of a variable exactly instead of just containing?

For example:

- `www.example.com/greenapples`
- `www.example.com/redapples`
- `www.example.com/greenapplesandpears`

If my URL is set as a variable `$myurl` and I use the following..

```
if (strstr($myurl, 'redapples')) {
echo 'This is red apples';
    }
```

Then it also applies to the other URLs as they also include the word apples. How can I be specific?

Comment: Why aren't you using strops()?

Comment: But if I used strpos wouldn't that also detect that the word apples is in all of the variables?

Comment: What's confusing is this: `match the content of a variable exactly instead of just containing` What does that mean?? to match exactly, use `==`.

Comment: If you're checking for `apples`, then yes... it will find `apples` in all of them; if you're testing for `redapples`, then it will only find it in one of them... perhaps you need to include `/` in your test string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehmm, just compare?

```
if ('www.mydomain.com/greenapples' === $myurl) {
    echo 'green apples!';
}
```

#### update

Without further info, I'm not sure if this fits your question, but if you're only interested in the last part of the URL *and* take into account the possibility that the URL contains a query-string (e.g. `?foo=bar&bar=foo`), try something like this:

```
// NOTE: $myurl should be INCLUDING 'http://'
$urlPath = parse_url($myurl, PHP_URL_PATH);

// split the elements of the URL 
$parts = explode('/', $urlPath);

// get the last 'element' of the path
$lastPart = end($parts);


switch($lastPart) {
    case 'greenapples':
        echo 'green!';
        break;

    case 'greenapplesandpears':
        echo 'green apples AND pears!';
        break;

    default:
        echo 'Unknown fruit family discovered!';

}
```

Documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: The URLs listed are just examples, they are dynamically generated usually so I can't match the entire URL

Comment: You should better explain what you actually want to compare

Comment: @fightstarr20: then you need try to rephrase your question. Matching whole strings should be done with === or preferably even `strcmp`, so to me it's a valid answer to your question as well :)

Comment: @Evert you're right, although I kinda expected this was not the answer OP was looking for. Probably a regexp will be required, but it really depends on **what** should match and what **not** (e.g. Should `/some/apples/and/pears/` match **_apples_** or **_pears_**?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PHP but this you should be able to do by using some string operations.
use 
substr("www.mydomain.com/greenapples",strripos("www.mydomain.com/greenapples", "/"));

strripos - returns last position of a substring, say its "/" in your case.
substr - return the substring after the given position

Something like this you can try.